# Trimming the path and redirect in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a Wordpress server at `www.mydomain.com/A/B`
The Nginx config is as:

```
server {
    listen 80 default;

    root /var/www/html;

  location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }


    location /A/B {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /A/B/index.php?$args;
    }
...
}
```

This is working fine.

What I want to do now is to redirect a legacy path to the new path.

Basically I want `www.mydomain.com/A/B/C/XXX/YYY/ZZZ` --> `www.mydomain.com/A/B/XXX/YYY/ZZZ`. Removing `/C`.

I believe I could do it with:

```
location /A/B/C {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /A/B/index.php?$args;
}
```

But it didn't work.
Then I tried

```
location /A/B/C {
    proxy_pass http://localhost/A/B;  # note the trailing slash here, it matters!
}
```

I think I maybe need another way since I need the `/XXX/YYY` path after the `/C`.

Any help appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: if the path is gone, consider to use `return 301 https://newpath;`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to rewrite the URL to remove the `C` path element.

For example:

```
rewrite ^(/A/B/)C/(.*)$ $1$2 permanent;
```

You can place this in the `server` block, or in a `location ^~ /A/B/C/` block.